# Which type of machine adopt of KMS instance from AWS for 500 to 500 (many to many) video conference

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, kurento, video-conferencing, screensharing

I have a situation that is many to many (500 to 500) video conference with audio or screen sharing.

so i want to know that in this situation which machine is suitable of amazon web service(AWS) for kurento media server.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will be able to recommend an instance type for your application. The reason is that **it all depends on the application, how many people use it, what they do, the patterns of usage, etc**.

The best way to determine such information is to use a **performance test** to simulate normal usage and run the test across many different instance types. Pick appropriate measures for each test to determine whether it meets your requirements. Such measures are not just things like available memory -- it's also **how the application *feels* from a user perspective**, such as whether it performs well or whether it seems slow.

Also, determine whether your application can **run across multiple servers rather than just a single server**. That way, when usage increases, the application can use **Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling** to scale-out and add more servers, then scale-in later when there is less demand (thereby saving costs). This also makes it more reliable because the failure of a single server will not impact the whole application.